@wordpress/create-block 'wp-scripts' is not recognized as a command
I am trying to create a standard Wordpress gutenberg block but I can't get paste the first step. I have cleared my npm cache but still getting the same error: 'wp-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
The node_modules folder is being created with all the dependencies of wp-scripts, but all the folders are empty? Very strange and I am not sure what I have to do here.
PS C:\Users\MyPath> npx @wordpress/create-block@latest

Let's customize your WordPress plugin with blocks:
? The template variant to use for this block: dynamic
? The block slug used for identification (also the output folder name): myblocks
? The internal namespace for the block name (something unique for your products): myblocks
? The display title for your block: My Blocks
? The short description for your block (optional): Example block scaffolded with Create Block tool.
? The dashicon to make it easier to identify your block (optional): smiley
? The category name to help users browse and discover your block: theme
? Do you want to customize the WordPress plugin? No

Creating a new WordPress plugin in the myblocks directory.

Creating a "block.json" file.

Creating a "package.json" file.

Installing `@wordpress/scripts` package. It might take a couple of minutes...

Formatting JavaScript files.
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\9444c7de6ab42aae\node_modules\execa\lib\error.js:59
                error = new Error(message);
                        ^

Error: Command failed with exit code 1: npm run format
'wp-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

> myblocks@0.1.0 format
> wp-scripts format

    at makeError (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\9444c7de6ab42aae\node_modules\execa\lib\error.js:59:11)
    at handlePromise (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\9444c7de6ab42aae\node_modules\execa\index.js:114:26)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async module.exports (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\9444c7de6ab42aae\node_modules\@wordpress\create-block\lib\init-wp-scripts.js:25:2)
    at async module.exports (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\9444c7de6ab42aae\node_modules\@wordpress\create-block\lib\scaffold.js:156:4)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\9444c7de6ab42aae\node_modules\@wordpress\create-block\lib\index.js:194:6) {
  shortMessage: 'Command failed with exit code 1: npm run format',
  command: 'npm run format',
  exitCode: 1,
  signal: undefined,
  signalDescription: undefined,
  stdout: '\n> myblocks@0.1.0 format\n> wp-scripts format\n',
  stderr: "'wp-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\n" +
    'operable program or batch file.',
  failed: true,
  timedOut: false,
  isCanceled: false,
  killed: false
}

Node.js v20.15.0

